# JQuery Div expand and scroll to bottom

Tags: jquery, html

im using jquery to expand a div when a button is clicked, here is the button code:

`<input type="button" value="Reply" onclick="jQuery('#replycont').slideToggle()"` />

and then obviously the actual div:

```
<div id="replycont" style="display:none; border:1px #000000 solid; padding:10px;">
<form method="post" action="index.php?id=viewticket&seq=<?php echo $_GET["seq"]; ?>#updates_bottom" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-stacked">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label bold" for="message">Message</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <textarea name="ticket_update" id="ticket_update" rows="12" style="width:100%;"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    <p><input type="hidden" name="ticketnumber" id="ticketnumber" value="<?php echo $_GET["seq"]; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="addupdate" id="addupdate" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
</div>
```

the button is at the top of the page and then the div is down the bottom, what would be the best way to make the page scroll to the bottom so the div is visible as well as the button expanding the div?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element

Answer (score 2):

It is preferred not to use inline js, add an id to your button, and then

```
$('#mybutton').on('click',function(){
$('#replycont').slideToggle(function(){
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#replycont').offset().top
}, 500);
});
});
```

And there you go, the animation will launch when the toggle is done, if you want it to run at the same time,

```
 $('#mybutton').on('click',function(){
$('#replycont').slideToggle();
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#replycont').offset().top
}, 500);
});
```

Comment: ok so ive added this for the button and the jquery:

<p><input type="button" id="reply-button" value="Reply" /></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#reply-button').on('click',function(){
$('#replycont').slideToggle();
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#replycont').offset().top
}, 500);
});
</script>

but its not working

Comment: just done this one:

$(function(){
 $('#reply-button').on('click',function(){
 $('#replycont').slideToggle();
 $('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $('#replycont').offset().top
 }, 500);
 });
}); 

but still nothing :(

Comment: does it need to go underneath the button html or above it?

Comment: like this:

<script type="text/javascript">$(function(){$('#reply-button').on('click',function(){ $('#replycont').slideToggle(); $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height().top }, 500); }); });</script>

still nothing - its not even expanding the div now (how confusing :/ )

Comment: just taken off the .top but still the same

Comment: chrome, safari and ie 9. im getting an error on dreamweaver though. did you save a new version of that fiddle?

Comment: well its working on jsfiddle but not on my site for some reason :/

Comment: @charliejsford Check the comment above i forgot to save it earlier :P if it works i ll edit the answer and let's delete these comments

Comment: @charliejsford Can you copy the error it is giving ? and make sure to include jquery ofc

Comment: no error - just not working. when i click the button its not doing anything

Comment: err...did you give the button the id `reply-button`?

Comment: yeah i did - its in the fiddle

Comment: @charliejsford Is there a link where i can see the website ? If it's not doing anything or any errors the listener on the button is not being attached properly

Comment: erm i cant coz its a client area that needs to be logged into. erm how about this new fiddle? - http://jsfiddle.net/G8TxZ/
its not working on there either

Comment: @charliejsford and now it is http://jsfiddle.net/G8TxZ/2/ :P You forgot to include jquery in your last fiddle

Comment: @charliejsford nop i added the margin and include jquery but it's the same fiddle you gave me

Comment: can you add a `console.log('test')` inside the click handler in your code

Answer (score 0):

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#replycont').offset().top
})
```

Comment: actually I did it opn my own :p